# Get client IP address from server

Tags: c#

I have a C# application than run in server. I want when users run my application with remote Application in Themselves computer. Then get client user IP Address in my application.

Thanks to all and sorry my English is poor.

My application is C# desktop application not web application

Comment: @amitdayama Did any where in question it is mentioned it is asp.net?

Comment: can you please share what is your client side and server side code?

Comment: i can get ip from server because my application run server

Comment: It depends upon the technology the client uses to connect to the server.  WCF/Remoting/Sockets/ASP.net?

Answer (score 0):

This returns the first IP4 address or null

```
return Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

You can have a look on the [IPHostEntry.AddressList Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.addresslist(VS.80).aspx) and [IPAddress.AddressFamily Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I believe his users are using RDP to connect to a terminal server. This will get the IP of the terminal server, not the IP of the connected user.